# Grunt watch task binding in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gruntjs, visual-studio-2015, grunt-contrib-watch

**Problem**: I have a problem to configure binding for grunt watch task to always run in Visual Studio 2015.

**My goal**: I want to watch files for changes and once the change occurs I want to run some task and then resume watch task to look for further changes.

**What I have tried so far**:

1. I have set binding for watch task on 'ProjectOpened', but it only
   does work then until I build my project. Once I build/rebuild my project the
   watch task stops handling the changes of tracked files.
2. I have tried binding my watch task to 'AfterBuild' and 'BeforeBuild', but having
       that set, the build operation hangs forever in Visual Studio (it just never ends).

Here's my gruntfile.js:

```
/// <binding AfterBuild='default' ProjectOpened='watch' />

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-task');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.initConfig({
    bower: {
        install: {
            options: {
                targetDir: 'wwwroot/vendor',
                layout: 'byComponent',
                install: true,
                cleanTargetDir: true,
            }
        }
    },
    less: {
        development: {
            files: { 'wwwroot/navbar.css': 'LessStyleSheets/navbar.less' }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        options: {
            interrupt: true
        },
        files: ['LessStyleSheets/navbar.less'],
        tasks: ['less']
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('default', ['bower:install', 'less']);
};
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the problem solved itself... After restarting Visual Studio the problem disappeard and the build process no longer hangs after running grunt watch task.